# How can I use CCFollow in cocos2d for android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to use CCFollow in my game. but I don't know How to use it.

In ZhouWeikuan-cocos2d Testbed project, CCFollow is used in this way

```
CCSprite grossini;
CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();

grossini.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(-200, winSize.height/2));

CCMoveBy move = CCMoveBy.action(2, CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width*3,0));
CCMoveBy move_back = move.reverse();
CCSequence seq = CCSequence.actions(move, move_back);
CCRepeatForever rep = CCRepeatForever.action(seq);

grossini.runAction(rep);

this.runAction(CCFollow.action(grossini, CGRect.make(0, 0, (winSize.width*2)-100, winSize.height)));
```

and here is the title of this Layer

"The sprite should be centered, even though it is being moved"

but it's not working. sprite is moving from side to side.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with boundaries. Try changing the runAction method:

```
this.runAction(CCFollow.action(grossini));
```